# How can a reduction Order be created programmatically

Tags: apex, sales-cloud

The [standard Order object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_order.htm) has a read-only checkbox/Boolean field called IsReductionOrder that is defined as:

> Read-only. Determines whether an order is a reduction order. Label is Reduction Order.

I have code to create a reduction Order as follows, but it doesn't work because the IsReductionOrder fields is read-only, which is consistent with the documentation.

```
Order originalOrder = getExistingOriginalActivatedOrderSomehow();

Order reductionOrder = new Order(
    IsReductionOrder = true,
    OriginalOrderId = originalOrder.Id,
    Pricebook2Id = originalOrder.Pricebook2Id,
    EffectiveDate = originalOrder.EffectiveDate,
    Status = 'Draft'
    AccountId = originalOrder.AccountId,
);

insert reductionOrder;
```

If I remove that line, I get an error that the OriginalOrderId field can only be used with reduction Orders (*FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can specify Original Order on reduction orders only.: []*).

**Question:** How can I create a reduction Order programmatically?

Definitely need it for unit tests.  I'm on Spring '14 with code that is API version 30.

Comment: Don't you need to create an original order first? Once you do, it appears as though you could create a reduction order in conjunction with an update to the original order.

Comment: @crmprogdev - The original Order is the originalOrder variable. I added a declaration line to the code to make it clearer.

Comment: My apologies. Was probably writing my comment at the time you were making the edit. Either that or I simply missed that detail. ;)

Comment: What happens if you remove `IsReductionOrder = true`; attempting to make it implicit that its a reduction order?

Comment: @crmprogdev - If I remove that line, I get an error that the OriginalOrderId field can only be used with reduction Orders "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can specify Original Order on reduction orders only.: []."

Comment: I saw that edit right after I commented.(sigh) Perhaps creating a generic sObject first that you then declare as a reduction order? Tough problem to solve. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this popped up in the documentation at some point for OriginalOrderId: "Editable only if isReductionOrder is true." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_order.htm

This should work as expected now:

```
Order reductionOrder = new Order(
IsReductionOrder = true,
OriginalOrderId = originalOrder.Id,
Pricebook2Id = originalOrder.Pricebook2Id,
EffectiveDate = originalOrder.EffectiveDate,
Status = 'Draft',
AccountId = originalOrder.AccountId);

insert reductionOrder;

//insert reduction order products here

reductionOrder.Status = 'Activated';
update reductionOrder;
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does work.

Comment: How can add Product to reductionOrder?